# Getting Error: Network Error at e.exports (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.g.onerror (xhr.js:117) for API call

Tags: javascript, api, axios, weather, openweathermap

I am trying to make an API request by Axios but am getting this error.

```
Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.g.onerror (xhr.js:117)
```

Here is the code:

```
    async function getData() {
  await axios
    .get(
      "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={api key}"
    )
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: More details needed. What is the network error you are getting? e.g. 403? 404? something else? And does it come with an error message?

Comment: I am also getting this:

Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mentioning the right protocol.

```
"https://api.openweathermap.org/..."
```

Make sure you're using the right URI path.  Also check your connectivity.  The values of `err` might be worth examining as well.

Comment: Oh, I was missing the HTTP protocol in the URL, silly me. Thanks a lot!